# Show data into other page using on button click ionic?

Tags: ionic2, pass-data

I am having this type of response

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "AttachmentFiles": [
                {
                    "odata": "SP.Attachment",
                    "odata": "AttachmentFiles('b1.jpg')",
                    "odata": AttachmentFiles('b1.jpg')",
                    "FileName": "b1.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "Article #1",
            "LongStory": "is designed to convey the business impact it generates.",
            "SortStory": "professional services firm ",
            "ArticleCategory": "News",

        },
        {
            "AttachmentFiles": [
                {
                    "odata": "SP.Attachment",
                    "odata": "https://('b3.jpg')",
                    "odata": "/AttachmentFiles('b3.jpg')",
                    "FileName": "b3.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "Id": 2,
            "LongStory": "In June 2017",
            "SortStory": "is a professional services
            "ArticleCategory": "News",
            "Title": "Article #2",

        }
    ]
```

}

I have to show long story on the other page with "FileName" value.

My code for html is below

```
<ion-content padding style="background:reds!important;" class="no-scroll">
    <ion-slides #slider (ionDidChange)="SlideChanged()" [options]="_sliderOptions" id="ionSlider" >
            <ion-slide #slide *ngFor="let robot of _robots; let i = index " >
                    <ion-item >
                             <div attr.id="Testing{{i}}"></div>>
                        <h1>{{robot.Title}}</h1>
                        <p>{{robot.SortStory}}</p>
                    </ion-item>
                    <button ion-button (click) = "goToLongStory()" icon-start large round color="dark">
                            <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
                            clike me m8
                          </button>
                </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

can Any one help me on this , on each slide i am having the button and on button click i have to show related data to other page like long story , title, filename.

Please help me .

Comment: What do you mean show the data on other page? Do you want to pass the object to a new page? Or do you want to show the data in the next slide?

Comment: pass object to new page and access Long Story.

Answer (score 1):

in your constrcutor put

`public navCtrl: NavController,`
`

than in your function goToLongStory() pass the index you want to access and filter for the long story with the index you need. Afterwards just call the new page and pass the parameter.

`this.navCtrl.push('newPage', { longStory: LongStory });`

On the page "newPage" you will need to add the following to your constrcutor:

`public navParams: NavParams`

than get the LongStory from navParams to a variable of your choice.

`let yourNewVariable: string = navParams.get("LongStory ");`

Comment: goToLongStory(indexOfLongStory){
    let longStroy:any = JSON.stringify(this._robots[indexOfLongStory]);
    let stringLong  = longStroy;
    let stringLong1 = stringLong.LongStory ;
   this.navCtrl.push(LongStoryPage,indexOfLongStory);
  }   i have done this but stringLong1 is undefined?? please help me why this is undefined.

Comment: just put a console.log after every declaration and check where it is undefined.

Comment: I am getting: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavController'.ts(2339)

Comment: if you can create a public repository on git or somewhere else I may can take a look into this